# Conditional Distribution expressed as product of expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My question is regarding a mathematical derivation of a conditional probability density function I found in paper.

Assume we have random variable

$$U_i = \begin{cases}
         1 & \text{with probability  $p_i =-\beta d_i $}\\
         0 & \text{if $1-p_i$}.\end{cases} $$

Also assume I am interested in computed the following $$\sum_{q=0}^\infty P({\bf u_q}=0 \mid Q=q)  P(Q=q)$$

where ${\bf u_q} = [U_1,\cdots, U_q]$.

The authors assume that for a given $Q=q$, we have that $\{d_1, d_2,\ldots, d_n\}$ are independent then they proceed to claim that

$$P({\bf u_q=0} \mid Q=q)= \prod_{i=1}^q \mathbb{E}[1- e^{\beta d_i}]$$

My question is regarding the last step, I dont understand why one can express the conditonal distribution as above.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be withholding a lot of information from us.  Are $U_1,U_2,U_3,\ldots$ supposed to be independent?  Or perhaps conditionally independent given $d_i,\  i=1,2,3,\ldots$?  You went on to say that $d_1,\ldots,d_n$ are independent without having said they are supposed to be random variables.  You've said nothing about their distribution.  And what is $n$?  You seem to allow the integer-valued random variable $Q$ to be any nonnegative integer, so maybe you meant $d_1,\ldots, d_Q$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You should have $\Pr({\bf u_q=0} \mid Q=q)= \prod_{i=1}^q (1- p_i)$.  So what you wrote makes sense if $p_i=\operatorname{E}(e^{\beta d_i})$.  But elsewhere you say $p_i=-\beta d_i$.  That $\operatorname{E}(e^{\beta d_i}) = -\beta d_i$ is strange since it has the random variable $d_i$ on one side and a non-random expected value on the other side. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks Michael, is it against the rules in this website to provide the link to the paper I got this info from? @MichaelHardy

Comment: A link is no problem. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6857368&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel7%2F4234%2F5534602%2F06857368.pdf%3Farnumber%3D6857368

Comment: Thanks, Michael I hope you have access to IEEE papers. The section I copied into this question here are exactly equations (5) (6) (7). I don't think I missed any details. @MichaelHardy